# Error hyde with python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyde

I followed (https://github.com/hyde/hyde) and installed all requirements.txt using the command "hyde-s folder_name create-l starter "error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C: \ Python33 \ Scripts \ hyde-script.py", line 9, in <module>
     load_entry_point ('== 0.8.4 hyde', 'console_scripts', 'hyde') ()
   File "C: \ Python33 \ lib \ site-packages \ hyde \ main.py", line 10, in main
     Engine (.) Run ()
   File "C: \ Python33 \ lib \ site-packages \ hyde \ engine.py", line 39, in run
     super (Engine, self). run (args)
   File "C: \ Python33 \ lib \ site-packages \ command \ application.py", line 252, in run
     self.parse args = (sys.argv [1:])
   File "C: \ Python33 \ lib \ site-packages \ command \ application.py", line 242, in parse
     self.__parser__.parse_args return () # pylint: disable-msg = E1101
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute '__parser__'
```

I saw the argparse that was installed has a "parse_args () (http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/parse_args.html)" tried unsuccessfully to adapt more.

Before I had to do a few adjustments example "from UserDict import IterableUserDict" as in "python 3x" has (http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict).

Comment: Python 3 has `argparse` included. That is not your problem here. Your traceback looks strange, what did you do to the filenames and the `_` in `self.parse_args = (sys.argv [1:])`?

Comment: At the very least `Typogrify` is not Python 3 compatible. I suspect this project *requires* Python 2.

Comment: Is Hyde still actively developed/maintained? The last commit on the repository you linked dates back to one year ago. Perhaps you could search for a different static site generator that supports Python 3 from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested two Static Site Generator and i can say that [Nikola](https://github.com/ralsina/nikola) and [Pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican) are the most stable for use with Python 3.3.2